# Is there a way to render encoded/compressed video files in Love2D?

Tags: video, lua, love2d

I'm trying to learn Love2D and Lua by jumping right in and making a game, and I was wondering if it was possible to do actual video playback of encoded video files in Love2D. Or should I just give up on that and draw a sequence of images for my intros and cutscenes?

Comment: It should be fairly obvious from the Love2D documentation whether or not it has video decompression as a feature. Do you see an API that would take video files? If not, then it can't.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this forum post](https://love2d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=7552), it looks like the answer is no.  You *may* be able to hack something together using GStreamer but that would only work on Linux; I don't think bindings exist for DirectShow or Quicktime, so that route probably isn't even worth exploring.

That said, if you've made an intro flashy enough to make it worth switching frameworks, it looks as though Moai does include [basic support for movie playback](http://getmoai.com/docs/class_m_o_a_i_movie_player_android.html).